# Recycler view images aren't clickable, to open up a new page

Tags: java, android, flickr

I'm trying to make each image within the RecyclerView clickable to open up the photo, along with its Title and a description, but all of this info is coming through Flickr, I've added in code that I thought should be suitable but it doesn't seem to be working, as none of the images are clicking, any guidance as to how to fix this is greatly appreciated.

Would a simple findByViewId() method in the details class suffice or is there more than I seem to be missing? Like I said, any help is appreciated.

Thank you!

ImageListAdapter Class

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
 import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

 /**
 * Created by Adam on 22/12/2017.
 */

public class ImageListAdapter
    extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ImageListAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private NetworkImageView imageThumbnail;

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView  imageTitle;
    public NetworkImageView mainImage;


    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        imageTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageTitle);
        mainImage = (NetworkImageView) 
 itemView.findViewById(R.id.mainImage);
    }
    private View.OnClickListener itemClicked = new View.OnClickListener() {
        int position = ViewHolder.this.getLayoutPosition();
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), 
 DetailsActivity.class);

              intent.putExtra("PHOTO_POSITION", position);
             imageThumbnail.setOnClickListener(itemClicked);

            itemView.getContext().startActivity(intent);
        }
    };
}
//Data Source
public ArrayList<ImageInfo> imageList = new ArrayList<ImageInfo>();

// context
private Context context;

public ImageListAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return imageList.size();
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    //Create the view for the cell in the list
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.cell_image_card, parent, false);

    ImageListAdapter.ViewHolder vh = new ImageListAdapter.ViewHolder(v);
    return vh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ImageInfo imageInfo = imageList.get(position);


    holder.imageTitle.setText(imageInfo.title);
    holder.mainImage.setImageUrl(imageInfo.url_m, 
NetworkMgr.getInstance(context).imageLoader);
 //   holder.mainImage.setImageResource(imageInfo.imageResource);

}


}
```

DetailsActivity Class

```
public class DetailsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public TextView imageTitle;
public NetworkImageView imageView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_details);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    photoPosition = intent.getIntExtra("PHOTO_POSITION", 0);

    titleView.setText(photo.title);
    imageView = NetworkMgr.getInstance(this).imageList.get(photoPosition);

}
}
```

Comment: add  imageTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageTitle);
        mainImage = (NetworkImageView)

Comment: @StringForever would i add this in DetailsActivity?

Comment: in ViewHolder  (View itemView)

Answer (score 1):

you are just forgetting to set the onClick listener on the mainImage view

**Step 1**: set the click listener on mainImage

```
   public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        final Context mContext = itemView.getContext();
        final int position = getAdapterPosition();
        imageTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageTitle);
        mainImage = (NetworkImageView) 
        itemView.findViewById(R.id.mainImage);
        mainImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, DetailsActivity.class);
          intent.putExtra("PHOTO_POSITION", position);
          mContext.startActivity(intent);
          }
       });
    }
```

Step 2: get the position like this in details activity

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_details);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    int position = intent.getIntExtra("PHOTO_POSITION", 0);
    ImageInfo imageInfo = NetworkMgr.getInstance(this).imageList.get(position);
    //use image info to get the image and title details.

}
```